# Removing empty rows from Table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove all empty rows from my table, but every time i click the button to do it, the table header gets removed too.

How can i fix this ?

Here's the fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S8CUa/155/)

To reproduce the issue, you need to do this:

1. Click `Edit Properties`.
2. Click `Add Row` and add a couple of properties (make sure you leave one row completely empty).
3. Click `Save`.
4. Click `Remove Empty Rows`.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: @JasonP it might be me, but i'm really not seeing how i can make my question clearer to you... I've included a JSFiddle with all the code i wrote, along with a detailed explanation on how to reproduce the issue. What do you want more?

Comment: The stackoverflow rules state that the code relevant to the question should be posted **in the question**, not on another non-stackoverflow website. The jsfiddle is a nice supplement, but the code should still be **in the text of the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are looking for td-tags in line 3 and your head has none td tag. Therefore the text is empty and it will deleted.

Comment: Thanks, super simple fix!

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/a8wLy18w/

I added a tbody so you can differentiate the body from the header

```
 <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover hide4" id="tab_properties">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center col-lg-3"> Property </th>
          <th class="text-center col-lg-4"> Value </th>
          <th class="text-center col-lg-1"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Then I changed your add and remove to use tbody in the jquery

```
$('#click').on('click', function() {
  $("#tab_properties tbody tr").each(function() {
    var cell = $.trim($(this).find('td').text());
    if (cell.length == 0) {
      console.log('empty');
      $(this).addClass('nodisplay');
    }
  });
});

$('#add_property').unbind('click').click(function() {
  $('#tab_properties tbody').append("<tr><td><input id=\"pn" + properties_id + "\" class=\"editable-input\"></td><td><input id=\"pv" + properties_id + "\" class=\"editable-input\"></td><td><div id=\"pr" + properties_id + "\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove_property\" type=\"button\" style=\"cursor:pointer\"></div></td></tr>");
  properties_id++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's another way to do it!